# Mapping a 3-D numpy array to a cube and visualize cross-sections

Tags: python, node-editor

I am trying to find the simplest way to load and render a 3-D array (currently in a numpy ndarray) as texture in Blender.

Essentially, what I am trying to do is like these:

https://twitter.com/j6m8/status/1483968956138508291

https://twitter.com/j6m8/status/1484276015006375943

I've contacted the author of this tweet, the way this was done is by using node-editor and converting a 3D array into a filmstrip and map the z-axis of the object into offset in the filmstrip.

I am trying to see if there is way to program this in bpy from a numpy array without needing to convert to an image and node-editor. Or directly use any Blender object that can support visualization of 3D array data? My goal is to integrate this into a Blender based addon we recently published

https://twitter.com/FangQ/status/1483122446467223553

Appreciated if you have any suggestions.

Comment: I don't have any useful info, but I did want to congratulate you on an excellent visualization tool.  Look forward to seeing what you accomplish with it.

Comment: thank you Marty for your encouragement!

Comment: This might ? be possible with OSL, have you explored that ? In regular node editor I think the preferred solution would be the one you described